# predicate return null while it should return list of values C#

Tags: c#, predicate

Good Day  To you all

I have issue with using 'predicate'
I'm trying to make function to return the results of some search text
here is the body of the function

```
public List<SaddadVM> GetAllBills(int Page = 1, int Take = 10, int? SearchField = null, string SearchItem = null)
{
     var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<SaddadVM>();
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchItem))
     {         
           predicate = predicate.And(x => x.BillAcct == SearchItem);
     }
     predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Id != 0);
     var bill = (from d in _context.Saddad
                    join R in _context.Requests on d.ReqId equals R.Id
                    join l in _context.Documenter on R.DocumenterId equals l.Id
                    where d.RecordStatus != GeneralEnums.RecordStatus.Deleted
                    select new SaddadVM
                    {
                        BillAcct = d.BillAcct,
                        ReqID = d.ReqId,
                        DocName = l.FullName,
                        DueDt = d.DueDt,
                        BillAmount = d.BillAmount

                    }).Where(predicate).Skip((Page - 1) * Take).Take(Take).ToList();
   
    return bill;
}
```

Knowing that the the Bill object should return at least 2 depending on running the same query on DB as follows :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePWvE.png)

Comment: By "return null" you mean that `bill` is null?

Comment: Maybe capture what query is actually being generated and executed. It seems.like that would answer it for you pretty quickly. We can't see that from here.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes bill is null but it shouldn't be

Comment: This seems impossible to me. `bill` is the result of `(some query).ToList()` and this cannot be null.

Comment: @KlausGütter that's what made me crazy ! it can't be null

Comment: So if you add a `Debug.Assert(bill != null)` it will fire?